# Couldn't click on buttons when child view is added?

Tags: android

When I use child view then the buttons which are in the root view are disabled. I could not click on them.
I am trying to develop application in which input is made by connecting buttons with lines. If user wants to enter
some thing then he have to touch buttons by connecting them with lines. It is very similar to android pattern
unlock. But in our application in place of dots of grid, numbers will be shown.

activity_demo_main:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rty" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DemoMainActivity" >

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="222.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="270.53426dp"

    android:text="1" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="162.08203dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="314.12678dp"

    android:text="2" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="87.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="314.12678dp"

    android:text="3" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27.917960dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="270.53423dp"

    android:text="4" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

DemoMainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.demo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class DemoMainActivity extends Activity {
 RelativeLayout rl;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_main);
     rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rty);


    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     final NewPattern b = new NewPattern(this);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try{
                rl.getRootView();
                rl.addView(b);



            }
                catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.demo_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

NewPattern.java:

```
 package com.example.demo;
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Path;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 //import com.example.newpattern.PatternMainActivity;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class NewPattern extends View 
{
private Paint m_paint;
private static Bitmap m_bitmap;
private Canvas m_canvas;
private Path m_path;
private Paint m_bitmapPaint;
private DisplayMetrics m_metrics;
private int m_color = 0xFFFF0000;
static boolean m_pathDrawn = false;
private float m_X, m_Y;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

RelativeLayout  rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rty);


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void touchman(float g, float h){
final float btn1x = b1.getX();
//float btn2x= b1.getY();
if(g==btn1x){
    rl.getRootView();
}
}
public NewPattern(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
//Your code
// btn1.setText("fdsf");
}

public NewPattern(Context p_c)
{
super(p_c);
try{

 m_paint = new Paint();
 m_paint.setAntiAlias(true);
 m_paint.setDither(true);
 m_paint.setColor(m_color);
 /*new ColorPickerDialog(p_c, new OnColorChangedListener()
 {
 public void colorChanged(int p_color)
 {
     m_paint.setColor(p_color);
     m_color = p_color;
 }
 }, 0xFFFF0000).show();*/
m_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
m_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
m_paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
m_paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
m_metrics = p_c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
m_bitmap =
     Bitmap.createBitmap(m_metrics.widthPixels, m_metrics.heightPixels,
             Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
m_canvas = new Canvas(m_bitmap);
m_path = new Path();
m_bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}
catch(Exception ex){}}

public void onerase()
{
m_canvas = null; 
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int p_w, int p_h, int p_oldw, int p_oldh)
{
super.onSizeChanged(p_w, p_h, p_oldw, p_oldh);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas p_canvas)
{try{

p_canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);
p_canvas.drawBitmap(m_bitmap, 0, 0, m_bitmapPaint);
p_canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);}
catch(Exception ex){}

}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void touch_start(float p_x, float p_y)
{//try{
 m_path.reset();
 m_path.moveTo(p_x, p_y);
 m_X = p_x;
 m_Y = p_y;

 //}
//catch(Exception ex){}
 }

 private void touch_move(float p_x, float p_y)
 {try{
 float m_dx = Math.abs(p_x - m_X);
 float m_dy = Math.abs(p_y - m_Y);
 if (m_dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || m_dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
 {
 m_path.quadTo(m_X, m_Y, (p_x + m_X) / 2, (p_y + m_Y) / 2);
 m_X = p_x;
 m_Y = p_y;
 m_pathDrawn = true;
}}
catch(Exception ex){}
}

private void touch_up()
{try{
m_path.lineTo(m_X, m_Y);
// commit the path to our offscreen
m_canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);
// kill this so we don't double draw
m_path.reset();
}
catch(Exception ex){}
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event)
{try{

float m_x = p_event.getX();
float m_y = p_event.getY();
switch (p_event.getAction())
 {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

         touch_start(m_x, m_y);
         //touchman(m_x, m_y);

         invalidate();
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


         touch_move(m_x, m_y);
        // touchman(m_x, m_y);
         invalidate();
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

         touch_up();
         //touchman(m_x, m_y);
         invalidate();
         break;
 }
return true; 
}
catch(Exception ex){}
return true;
}}
```

Comment: `NewPattern.java` shouldn't compile.

Comment: Then what to do. I m new to android programming.